# How to style the Status (Notification) bar in my activity

Tags: android, transparent, statusbar

I have seen a few activities out there (and especially Home replacements) that actually have transparent/translucent status bar (and by that I really mean the status bar and not the title bar) and was wondering how they were doing it.

I've looked everywhere (Google, StackOverflow, etc) and haven't found a straight answer to this question, tried a lot of things myself but in vain... Now running out of options and the only one I have left is to set the activity FULLSCREEN and have a replacement for it (there are a few projects out there that offer replacements for the status bar, but I'd rather not go that far for such a simple task really).

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've found my answer after studying how others "did it"... They actually didn't.

My guess goes a little further than that since I think that my status bar IS actually transparent just like those applications, but the real difference is that they are using the 2D/live wallpapers rendered by Android as background which is rendered behind the status bar.

So the reason why I'm thinking I don't have a transparent status bar is because in my case only black is being rendered behind it...

I don't have a phone here with a opaque status bar but I'm pretty sure those apps will also have an opaque status bar (and not transparent).

Answer (score 0):

You have looked every where except android developers official website.You can customize ur status(notification) bar.[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) 
is the link where u can get the custom notification bar tutorial.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, I do not want to customize a notification (been there, done that), but I want to customize the notification bar itself.

And believe me, I've checked everywhere.

Comment: Yeah thanks I saw there were some replacement for the status bar but it's a little bit too much for the small changes I want to do.

Dunno... I guess I'll check later if still can't find a better solution, thanks for the link :)